# ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a problem with my road and I do not understand why he told me "Dashboard::TasksController "
because in my controller file contains the file dashbaord / tasks.rb

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

def add_task
    @t = "test"
end
```

end

in my config / routes file I did this

```
match '/dashboard/add-task' => "dashboard/tasks#add_task", via: [:get, :post]
```

in folder view view/dashbaord/tasks/add_task.html.erb

So I do not see or is my mistake.

Thank you

Comment: You refer to your `TasksController` as if it's namespaced with `Dashboard`. Is it?

Comment: it is because you routed it there: 'dashboard/tasks#add_task" if you would do 'tasks#add_task' then it would look for TasksController
what are you trying to accomplish? just simply add this one route?

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
In my case I have a dashboard controller and file in the folder I have my controller tasks.rb which gives: /controllers/dashboard/tasks.rb , I'm going to work my way which is: / dashboard / add-Task years in my routes.rb file I put this: match '/ dashboard / add-task' => "dashboard / tasks # add_task" via: [: get,: post]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, your controller file should be named `tasks_controller.rb`.
Secondly, your `TasksController` should be namespaced:

```
class Dashboard::TasksController < ApplicationController
  # content
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't generated the controller using Rails CLI, and because of that I mistyped the filename...